# Let $G$ be a group and $c\in G$. Define $*$ on $G$ by: $x*y=xdy$ for all $x,y\in G$, where $d$ is the inverse of $c$. Prove $(G,*)$ is a group.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $c$ be a fixed element of $G$. Define a new operation $*$ on G by:
>   $$x*y=xdy$$
>   for all $x$ and $y$ in $G$, where $d$ is the inverse of $c$. Prove that $G$ is a group under the operation $*$.

- If you want to check, this problem is in the book *“A Course In Group Theory”*, by John F. Humphreys (problem $3$, page $28$)

I know what are the axioms that $(G,*)$ must obey in order to be a group and I did show that all the axioms where obeyed except the inverse axiom.

My **problem** is that, whenever I try to **verify what would the inverse be for some element $x$**, I get an equation where the $x$ is cancelled in both sides.

Can please someone *guide me*?

Thank you!

*(P.S.: This is NOT a homework assignment, I’m studying Group Theory by this book and got problems solving this question)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $\;x*y:=xc^{-1}y\;$ . Then closure is immediate, for associativity:

$$x*(y*z)=x*(yc^{-1}z)=xc^{-1}yc^{-1}z=(x*y)*z$$

and the unit:

$$x=x*h=xc^{-1}h\implies h=c\implies x*c=c*x=xc^{-1}c=x$$

and thus inverse of $\;x\in G\;$ :

$$c=x*a=xc^{-1}a\implies a=cx^{-1}c$$

Do some order in the above and that's your proof.

Comment: But in the end, we are saying that the inverse of an element $x$ is the inverse itself times $c$ in the left and times $c$ in the right? What is causing me confusion is that we are defining the inverse of $x$ In terms of itself... isn’t that some sort of cyclic definition?

Comment: Although, $c$ is the identity in this operation... so the $x^{-1}=x^{-1}$, am I thinking right?

Comment: Well, isn't the inverse of $\;g\;$ in some grouo $\;g^{-1}\;$ ...defined in terms of itself?! Shouldn't it be like this **always**?

Comment: But in your proof the inverse of $x$ is $a$ and $a$ depends on the inverse of $x$ which is $a$... this is kinda cyclic

Comment: @LeibnizRib Did you already checked carefully the proof I sent you? Did you write it down, think it over...and found something wrong with it?! Observe that the last part of my answer refers to the inverse of $\;x\;$ **with respect to the new defined operation**, and $\;x^{-1}\;$ is the inverse of $\;x\;$ in the *given, original, group operation of* $\;G\;$ ...

Comment: Oh I am really sorry, I miss that! You are right! Now I really got and the whole proof makes sense to me! Thank you!!